# Search file with camelcase in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I recall one of my colleague used to search file with camel Case. For example :- If my file name is CustomerSearchService.java then I can see this file just typing CSS in search. But i don't recall which setting needs to be done in eclipse.

I tried Control + Shift + R and typed CSS, but that file does not display on search result?

Comment: To search for a Java class, you should use Ctrl-Shift-T instead. R is for Resources. T is for Types.

Comment: I don't think there is a setting for this, it should always work in Open Resource, Open Type and similar dialogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *does* work for **Open Type** and **Open Resource**.
[image]

Comment: Thanks it works. I was trying lowercase. Looks like it works with uppercase only

Answer (score 0):

Using either **Open Type** or **Open Resource** (ie, File), you can do:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (for Java types) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (for any resource/file)
2. Type an abbreviation of just the capital letters of a type or file name (such as "CSS" for "CustomerSearchService")
3. Any matching types or files are listed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select check-box of "show camel case matches" in eclipse under windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> sort proposal

Answer (score 0):

What I found, is that the matching works only when the camel case starts with an upper-case letter, as is the case with Java class naming. It doesn't work for files whose filename starts with a lowercase letter, however.

### Example

If I have a file named **myLongNamedFile.xml**, search string **mLNF** won't find it. (Neither will the search string *MLNF*, for that matter.)

If it was named **MyLongNamedFile.xml**, search string **MLNF** would find it.